# Creating a new dataframe where a field is blank in the original dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Using Python3 and Pandas. I am admittedly pretty new and I'm having a hard time searching for an answer to this question.

I have a dataframe that contains lots of information and I'm trying to get a dataframe that is just the items where one specific field in the original is blank.

I have queried my database to get a dataframe I am calling full_df which is all information on all items in the database. I want to now create a new dataframe that selects just the items where one field in full_df is blank.

This is what I've tried:

```
no_rate = full_df[(full_df['rate'] == "")]
```

Which is returning nothing even though I know for a fact that there are loads of items where 'rate' is blank. I expected the dataframe no_rate to be populated with all the items where 'rate' is blank.

How do I select those items for this new dataframe?

Comment: What do you mean with blank? Maybe it is NaN or None? Then you would need full_df[full_df['rate'] is np.Nan]  or    full_df[full_df['rate'] is None]. If this doenst help please show us one of your rows

Comment: @tetrisprogramming good questions. The dtype for that column is object. It is showing as NaN and sometimes None for the ones I want to select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things you need to do. First of all, is the data type of your rate column a string, or object? `df.dtypes` will tell you. If not, then you can't test it against `""`.

Second, and more to the point, a way to do a conditional select is by useing `loc`.

So, if your rate column looks like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Rate': ['good', 'good', 'bad', 'medium', '', 'bad', '', 'good']})
df

    Rate
0   good
1   good
2   bad
3   medium
4   
5   bad
6   
7   good
```

then you could write

```
df.loc[df['Rate']==""]
```

and get

```
    Rate
4   
6
```

which is actually showing you the contents, but since there is nothing in there, it looks like just the row numbers. Let's add another column to see the results more plainly.

```
df['Color'] = ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Red', 'Yellow', 'Red', 'Green', 'Blue']
df
    Rate    Color
0   good    Red
1   good    Blue
2   bad Yellow
3   medium  Red
4       Yellow
5   bad Red
6       Green
7   good    Blue
```

and

```
df.loc[df['Rate'] == ""]
```

shows

```
    Rate    Color
4       Yellow
6       Green
```

So, what if your rate is actually a number

```
df['Decimal_Rate'] = [.8, .8, .3, .6, np.nan, .2, np.nan, .9]
df
    Rate    Color   Decimal_Rate
0   good    Red 0.8
1   good    Blue    0.8
2   bad Yellow  0.3
3   medium  Red 0.6
4       Yellow  
5   bad Red 0.2
6       Green   
7   good    Blue    0.9
```

if you wanted to isolate the empty cells of numbers, you can go like this:

```
df.loc[df['Decimal_Rate'].isna()]
```

which results in

```
    Rate    Color   Decimal_Rate
4       Yellow  
6       Green
```

Comment: Thank you! This showed me a lot of things I needed to know and learn. The thing that did the trick was df.loc[df['rate'].isna()]. So since that field has dtype object and is populated with numbers I needed to use loc and .isna() to select the locations where there is no number. Am I understanding that correctly?

Comment: If the dtype is 'object', no, that means you have strings in there, and you have empty strings in the empty columns, which will also give you a True result for isna(). But if you want actual numbers that you can do math with, you will need to covert rate to a data type that is numeric. ```df['Rate'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Rate'])``` is one way, or use ```df['Rate'].astype('float')```.  Or do it when you read in your data ```pd.read_csv('datafile.csv', dtype={'Rate': 'np.float64'})```. Create the Decimal_Rate column that I made as a sample, and then do df.dtypes to see what I mean.